Как задать размер шрифта и сам стиль шрифта к тексте в select option без увелечения самого выбора
Есть такой код:
    <div class="hid-spis">
        <select
          onchange="if (this.value) window.open(this.value, '_blank');"
          id="city-dropdown1">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Покупателям</option>
          <option value="https://www.gismeteo.ru">gismeteo</option>
          <option value="http://www.nova-wings.ru/forecast/">nova-wings</option>
        </select>
      </div>

Как в нем увеличить текст, но при этом, что бы не увеливалась сама выборка на странице, пример скриншотами ниже



В стили для ваших options пропишите нужный font-size. В вашем коде указан только один стилевой класс hid-spis - добавьте его код в вопрос, а лучше все стили, которые задействованы для отрисовки данного селекта
